# How to define class variables using the functions and variables of an instance in Python

Tags: python, class, scope

Is there a way to define a class variable using the variables and functions of the instance? Thanks

The simplified code looks like this:

```
def ClassA():
    X = self.func(self.a)

    def __init__(self, avalue):
        self.a = avalue

    def func(self):
        return self.a + 5
```

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You cannot do that because class must exist before class instance.

Comment: You can set class variables from an instance, yes. You cannot access any instance variables before you even have an instance. Perhaps you're misunderstanding what an instance is exactly…?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you define a Class using `class`, not `def`.

`self` only needs to be used inside of the class' function definitions, because they change the scope. Outside of them you don't need it:
`x = func(a)`.

But your code wouldn't work anyways because the instance doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you tried to do was:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self,avalue):
        self.a = avalue
        self.X = self.func

    def func(self):
        return self.a + 5

b = ClassA(43)
b.X()
```

outputs

```
48
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 0

    def m(self):
        A.x = 1

b = A()
#print(b.x) doesn't work here since we haven't made it yet. 
b.m() 
print(b.x) #1
c = A()
print(c.x) #1
A.x = 2
print(c.x) #2
print(b.x) #2 
print(vars(A)) #{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__module__': 'builtins', 'x': 2, '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x7f15f800d730>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'm': <function A.m at 0x7f15f800d7b8>}
```

Would you be looking for something like this?